# how to retrieve system's log out time?

Tags: java

i wanna develope a application which keeps record of daily login & logout time.
i solved login time but i dont know how to retrieve logout time.plz give me suggetion.
required any jar file??

i used following code for login time

```
        Process uptimeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net stats srv");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uptimeProc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            if(line.contains("Statistics since"))
                {
                   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("'Statistics since' M/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");

                    Date boottime = format.parse(line);
                    break;
                 }
        }
```

& it works very well.i am expecting suggestion for how to log out time retrieve.

Comment: :: http://superuser.com/questions/142605/windows-7-uptime-last-user-logged-in-time-and-date-last-rebooted  See This Link it may help you

Comment: is it possible to put java file in which we will get current time & we can put that file in system's folder then it will automatically execute at the time of shut down & will get logout time?